# Loop over first and last element only

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Given `N` elements, process only the first (0) and last (N-1) element.

But, if `N = 1`, only process the single element once.

Using a loop that runs once or twice, as appropriate, lets us avoid duplicating the loop body.  If there's a readable way to do this, it has a benefit for source-code size.  It may also have advantages for machine-code size, if the loop body is large, and the compiler doesn't end up duplicating it.

---

I tried incrementing by `N-1` but it will not work when `N=1` (loops forever). Are there tricks (reverse loop f.i) that will fix this?

```
for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i += (N - 1))
```

## Edit:

My original problem concerns three nested loops in x,y,z direction, which is why I couldn't just process elem[0]) and elem[N-1]. Now I have the following

```
#define forEachLglBound(i_,j_,k_)                                   \
        for(Int i_ = 0;i_ < NPX;i_+=((NPX>1) ? (NPX-1) : 1))        \
            for(Int j_ = 0;j_ < NPY;j_+=((NPY>1) ? (NPY-1) : 1))    \
                for(Int k_ = 0;k_ < NPZ;k_+=((NPZ>1) ? (NPZ-1) : 1))
```

---

Comment: Why do you need a loop for a constant two elements?

Comment: why would you need a for loop if you only want to access the first and last element

Comment: Why? Just write a function to do the work and call it with `array[0]` and `array[N-1]`. The intention will be much clearer.

Comment: I don't know what are you doing but if you need the first and last number, why you are using a loop? if you have an array then you can use something like: array[0] and array[size - 1], always check that the size is bigger than 1.

Comment: I have three nested loops of that kind (x,y,z) directions, where N is an integer from 1 to 15 max.

Comment: show your work, for better help

Comment: That will do the work twice (i=0). I want to do it once when N=1. With what I have it loops forever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about the following line. Very close (textwise!) to the original solution.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i += (N > 1) ? N-1 : 1)
```

Comment: The *ternary* operator has many unique uses. At first blush it may look like a rather odd bit of logic, but its inline conditional decision making extends what otherwise would not be possible in many useful ways.

Comment: This compiles to [fairly good code](http://goo.gl/OxdrQW), but isn't very easy to read, IMO.  I think my answer is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

If you can factor the loop body out into a function or macro, probably the most readable way is:

```
process( arr[0] );
if (N-1 != 0)
    process( arr[N-1] );
```

---

If that's not an option, or you think one of these loop structures is readable enough:

XOR can toggle a variable between 0 and the value you XOR with.

```
int i=0;
do {
    process(arr[i]);
} while(i ^= (N-1));  // xor to toggle, but stays zero if N-1 is zero
```

This **compiles to better asm than any of the other options**, [as you can see on godbolt](http://goo.gl/510rWc).  I included the ideas from the other answers, including the simple `if` (which does very well when duplicating the operation is cheap).

The xor version keeps working very well in a triple-nested loop (see the `while_xor_triple` function at the bottom of the godbolt link).

---

Without using xor, I think this loop is moderately readable:

```
int i=0;
do {
    process( arr[i] );
} while( (i!=N-1) && (i=N-1) );
```

if `i` isn't already `N-1`, set it to that and redo the loop.  This should make it easy for the compiler to do the test efficiently, without having to compute any expressions other than N-1.  gcc still tests and branches on both operands of the `&&` separately, though, but with less overhead than some of the other answers.

---

The 2nd while loop could compile to something like this (but unfortunately doesn't, because gcc doesn't do the trickery of my first two insns):

```
    xor   edx, edx
.repeat:
    mov   ecx, edx
      ... loop body using i (ecx)
    mov   edx, [N]
    dec   edx     ; edx = N-1
    cmp   ecx, edx
    jne .repeat
```

I thought of the XOR idea while thinking about how to do it in asm.  IDK if a smart compiler could make this output from the `while(i!=N-1 && i=N-1)` version, but it's definitely better:

```
    xor   ecx, ecx
.repeat:
      ... loop body using i (ecx)
    mov   edx, [N]
    dec   edx        ; edx = N-1
    xor   ecx, edx   ; i ^= N-1
    jnz .repeat      ; jump if the last result wasn't zero
```

If you have `N-1` stored in a register or memory, the `mov/dec` to compute it on the fly go away.

Comment: Excellent answer.  Of course, we should all remember the first rule of optimization: optimize algorithms, not code.  Only rarely is it necessary to optimize code!  PS: congrats on reaching 100K reputation!

Comment: @JeffLearman: Yes, algorithmic improvements can be huge, but efficient asm for an efficient algorithm sometimes requires some hand-holding for the compiler, and can be worth it for hot loops.  see [Why is this C++ code faster than my hand-written assembly for testing the Collatz conjecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354978) and especially [What is the efficient way to count set bits at a position or lower?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34410357) for an example of hand-holding the compiler into more efficient asm for the same thing.

Comment: Or especially when manually vectorizing with SIMD intrinsics, or even a loop that you want to auto-vectorize, thinking about / looking at the compiler's asm can give you significant speedups.  And BTW, thanks, that 100k has been a long time coming, answering in tags that don't get as much attention as C++ or especially C# / Java.  I'm also the only SO user to have a [tag:x86-64] gold badge, and was the first to get [tag:x86] gold :)

Answer (score 3):

```
for ( i = 0, repeat = 0; repeat < 2 && repeat < N; repeat++, i = N-1 )
```

or

```
repeat = (N<2) ? N : 2;
for ( i = 0; repeat > 0; repeat--, i = N-1 )
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that may be the only way.

Answer (score -1):

How about this, though don't have to use a `for loop` maybe, but it's a simple way and easy to understand.

```
for (int first = 0, last = N - 1;;) {
     // the stuff use first
     if (first != last) {
     // the stuff use last
     }
     break;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't avoid running `stuff` twice on the same element when `N=1`.  That's the only reason this question isn't trivial.

Comment: The stuff use the first and last doesn't mean use first twice! @PeterCordes

Comment: The `for { ... ; break; }` structure is doing exactly nothing.  Still a downvote, because if you want to tell him to just use an `if` and repeat the `stuff`, say that.

Comment: `if (first != last)` This means when `N = 1`, the elements is not processed even once.